# Possible permission required by a new extension?

Tags: css, image, url, google-chrome-extension, document-body

Basically, I am writing an extension that replaces the background image of websites. I use CSS to replace the background image with images in the extension.
Here is my style.css:

```
body {
background-image:url(  chrome-extension://moeiggeeiijobkphiljnhlpndjmmpohc/options/smile.jpg ) !important;
```

}

I don't know why this doesn't work. The url path is correct; if I type it into the address bar, the image smile.jpg will be shown. 
I also have tried to replace the url with images from other extension that I have installed, like "chrome-extension://pkmbgbnldenjnbgbigpkjokfdfgmmclo/icon-15.png"
And it works.

Therefore, I assume that somehow images in my extension can't be accessed by the css. Is there any permission that I need to get?

Comment: did you checked that extension name was of the correct type ? smile.jpg, but it's in fact a png hold in the file .It happened to me before.

Comment: - GCyrillus, The type is correct. As I said, if I type it into my address bar, the image can be shown. If the type is wrong, then the image can't be shown.

Comment: i mean, open file in text editor and check that it is a real jpeg and not a png or else. in other words, are your extension and image/type are coherent ?

Comment: Yes, it is a real jpg/jpeg image, I downloaded it from a website, and have never changed its type.

Comment: oki, i have no more clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to define the image as a [web-accessible resource](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources). Add this to your manifest file and you should be good to go!:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
  "options/smile.jpg"
]
```